# Implementing a one to one (1:1) relationship between Person and User

Tags: mysql, database-design, mysql-5.5, entity-framework, subtypes

## Scenario description

I have this `person` table as super parent (or supertype),

```
id
firstname
lastname
email
telephone
...
...
```

and `user` table as a child (or subtype)

```
id
person_id (FK)
password
username
screenname
...
...
```

They must be in a one-to-one (**1:1**) relationship, because an *user* cannot be repeated twice, and so a particular *email* value in a given *person* row must not be repeated twice.

Then I have this `message` table which stores *messages* from anyone,

```
id
firstname
lastname
email
telephone
subject
content
...
...
```

but you can see that `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`, `telephone` are **duplicated** in the `message` table.

So, I am thinking to refer it to `person` table like this below,

```
id
person_id
subject
content
...
```

but then it does not seem right, as a *person* with the same *email*, *name*, etc. can send a *message* to me as many times as they want, so the details he/she provides can be repeated.

## Questions

- So, should I make `message` as a child of `person` the parent or they should be separate entities?
- Or, are there any better suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have a `person` table.

Fine (just changed the name of the PK column):

```
person
------
person_id    PK
firstname
lastname
email
telephone
...
...
```

> and a user table as a child. They must be 1:1 relationship, because an user cannot be repeated twice.

If the relationship is 1:1 (assuming that `person` is the supertpe and `user` is the subtype, you can handle this with having the same column both as Primary Key and Foreign Key to `person`:

```
user
----
person_id  PK  FK to person(person_id)
password
username
screenname
...
...
```

> and so the email in the person row must not be repeated twice.

Add a `UNIQUE` constraint in the `person.email` column.

> Then I have this message table which stores messages from anyone,
>   but you can see that firstname,lastname, email,telephone are duplicated in message table.
>   so I am thinking to refer it to person table like this below.

Fine (adjusted to previous changes). But you also need to store who sends a message and who is the receiver:

```
message
-------
message_id   PK
sender_id    FK  to user(person_id)         --- or to person(person_id)
receiver_id  FK  to user(person_id)         --- that depends on your requirements
subject
content
...
```